# Handle 3 pub sub messages coming at same time , combine all 3 and store it in fire store

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I Have 3 Pub Sub triggered cloud functions which receives 3 different Messages. These are published at the same time.

1. Main Data.
2. Sub Data 1.
3. Sub Data 2.

These messages has to be written into the firestore based on some logic.

Intended Goal:
Sub data 1 and Sub Data 2 has to be combined and outcome should be inserted into the Main Data document. After combining sub data 1&2, it knows the main data path(fire store document path) where it needs to attach itself.

Issues :

The cloud functions has to store their respective message data into firestore before it gets attached into the main data. Also main data has to be inserted before the sub data 1&2 combined, so that combined sub data 1&2 can be attached into the main data as extra.

What I have tried:

Tried orphan/parent storage logic. It works like,

```
Sub data 1 comes->looks for sub data 2 in its orphaned path , Combines with it ->
knows the main data path-> attach into it, if main data document is not available yet, get stored into the orphaned collection

 or 

Sub data 1 comes->looks for sub data 2, data 2 not available. Stored into the Orphaned collection.

If sub data 2 comes, 
  Sub data 2 comes->looks for sub data 1 , combines with it ,knows the main data path
  ->attach into it, if main data document is not available yet.stored 
  into the orphaned collection
```

When Main data inserted into the firestore, it will look for this sub data in the orphaned collection, if it is available, will attach those into it

Since these messages coming at the same time, exactly milliseconds interval, this logic is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches worth considering here. If you know how long you need to wait, you can start functions that need to wait with a "sleep" function and just have them tread water for a bit (this is a bit hacky and could be costly at scale, but it works):

```
async function sleep(milliseconds) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
sleep(5000)
```

Likely a better solution would be to ditch the pub/sub messages for the subsequent functions and instead switch them to http functions and have the first function call them via a simple fetch request.

From whichever function you want to call first:

```
// ... do some stuff, then fetch when ready
let res = await fetch(
    "https://us-central1-projectName.cloudfunctions.net/secondFunction",
    {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    }
);
```

You can secure these functions with a bearer token, as [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_function_to_function_calls).

Comment: The Messages are coming from the third party rabbit mq server . Our Pub sub is subscribed to those rabbit mq topics. Putting those sub data messages into the pub sub pull subscription and getting it from the main data will add more logics, if there are more than 2 messages.

Comment: I Fixed the issue using Pub Sub retries along with exponential back off time.

Sub data 1 push subscription will be always written to an orphaned collection.

Main data will be written to its respective collection.

Sub data 2 push subscription will always look out for Sub Data 1 and Main data while it is executing. If either one is not available at it's execution time, it will NACK the pub sub message, so it will be retried after 10-15 seconds. The maximum retry attempts are 5 times.

Comment: The Pub sub retry flow kind of backfired. Whenever the push subscription nacks the message, pub sub delayed the new messages. Considering 100 messages in a minute, due to this delay , pub sub queue started to fill up.